# Dump Kubernetes log files for all services/pods/jobs etc

Tags: kubernetes

We are remotely deploying a kubernetes cluster and when the installation fails, we would like to see the logs of all the services and migrations and pods etc. that we are trying to install.
Instead of manually specifying each specific service etc. Is there an easy way of getting all the logs of the cluster and saving them in a tar file.

Answer (score 1):

You are possibly looking for a third party stack on cluster to help you, if so there is long list you can explore and play to your need

Various Kubernetes logging tools you could consider from below list:

> [Fluentd](https://docs.fluentd.org/container-deployment/kubernetes)
>
> [ELK Stack](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/logging-elasticsearch-kibana/)
>
> [Stackdriver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/logging-stackdriver/)

I have used this link to setup [EFK](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-elasticsearch-fluentd-and-kibana-efk-logging-stack-on-kubernetes) on my local cluster.